# Manually set user's Roles in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, authentication

I have some JSF 2 applications that are currently working with a JSF Secutiry LoginModule (auth-method = FORM). But authentication will be done now through a new way, that means I'll have to manually program the authentication interactions.

That's fine, but now I have problems setting the roles. I couldn't find where I can set the Principals, or get subject to do it, or get shared state to put "javax.security.auth.principal" and "javax.security.auth.roles" variables.

Is there a way to do it? Here is a sample of my actual Bean code.

Thanks in advance!

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PrincipalController extends AbstractController implements ExcluirRascunhoService.Presenter {

    // has get and set      
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{autenticacaoController}")
    private AutenticacaoController autenticacaoController;


    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        try {
                // a previous application redirected the user here, 
                // giving two parameters, including a valid and calculated HASH
                // to be passed to authentication

            Map<String, String> requestMap = getContext().getRequestParameterMap();
                String user = (String) requestMap.get("login");
                String hash = (String) requestMap.get("hash");

                // this will do the authentication, communicating with a
                // webservice and passing these data so the webservice can
                // authenticate the data, telling me if the user is Ok
                autenticacaoController.authenticate(user, hash); 

                // do the other things if authentication doesn't throw an exception    

                // I should now fill all user's Roles accordingly to my database
                // I get them correctly, but how to set them into the JSF Roles?
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                // catch and quit the page
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: JSF does not do any authentication, nor does it have 'roles'..  So you have to be more explicit in what you want to achieve, what the 'new' part is etc... Currently the question is 'unclear what you ask' and if not improved, most likely will be flagged for this.

Comment: If your application server is an implementation of the Full Java EE 6 or 7 Profile, the standard type providing the functionality you are looking for (i.e., authentication and registration of authenticated caller `Principal`s and their roles with the Servlet / EJB container) is [`ServerAuthModule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/security/auth/message/module/ServerAuthModule.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with JSF alone. Basically, JSF only provide a utility to get the user and it's role directly from the JSF interface. So, if you want to access the principal user and it's roles from your application you must first authenticate the user.

To authenticate your user you can use an third party solution like JAAS or Apache Shiro to setup the realm, roles and control the authentications of your application.

You can also roll your own authentication layer, which may not give you the possibility to use some useful JSF utilities like getting the principal user or it's roles directly from the realm (note that your custom layer will probably provide other ways to get these values), but will also provide a custom way to do the authentication required.

I have found a pretty nice tutorial about [JAAS authentication layer](http://uaihebert.com/validacao-de-login-de-usuario-com-jsf-e-jaas/#) (in portuguese) that may help you setting up a authentication layer.

Wish you good luck and feel free to ask if you have any doubts about what I've said.

Comment: So, I have to manually control access to pages with a filter or something like, removing the roles?

Comment: Not necessarily, as I said, you can use some authentication APIs that supports role systems.